# MD5 Bizarre Behavior on Android

Tags: java, android, md5

I have a simple method that takes in a String and hashes it with the MD5 algorithm (needless to say that all these `sysos` are for monitoring/debugging the weird behaviors I've been experiencing) :

```
private String hashMD5(String input) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

    // BYTES_ENCODING == "UTF-8"
    digest.update(input.getBytes(BYTES_ENCODING), 0, input.length());

    System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16));
    System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16));
    System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16));

    String hash = new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16);
    System.out.println(hash + " : used hash");
    System.out.println(hash.length() + " - " + new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16).length());
    return hash;
}
```

When calling this method with a set String, here's what I get:

```
02-18 08:49:23.355: I/System.out(2753): 78bfa0ce6d53a698a98aac899562bb4
02-18 08:49:23.355: I/System.out(2753): d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
02-18 08:49:23.355: I/System.out(2753): d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
02-18 08:49:23.355: I/System.out(2753): d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e : used hash
02-18 08:49:23.355: I/System.out(2753): 32 - 32
```

So my question to you all is:

*Why would the first `BigInteger` be any different from all of the other ones (in length and in content) ?*

I'm experiencing this same behavior on both of my testing devices, where I must create at least 2 `BigInteger` to get a hash of the right length:

1. Nexus S (Android 4.1.1)
2. Nexus 7 (Android 4.2.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the first digest.update() updates the digest but do not reset the MessageDigest instence. Then the first result that is printed is the hash of input.getBytes(BYTES_ENCODING), 0, input.length()) concatenated with new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16)

Comment the line that reads digest.update(...)

Note that BigInteger.toString() does only convert a byte array to hexadecimal. It does not append any leading zero.

```
String s = new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16);
while (s.length()<16) s="0"+s; //or something else to the same effect
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Okay, so you're telling me that, currently only the first print gets me the value of the hash for the string that I entered in the method and all the other prints are hashing a default MessageDigest value ?

Comment: Also, how would that explain that the length of the first value isn't the length of a standard MD5 hash, I'm quite confused to be honest.

Comment: No. See [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) 

The digest(...) methods complete the hash computation, perform the final update, reset the state of the digest and returns the result. 

The update(...) operations updates the digest, do not return any value, and do not reset the digest.

What happens is that in the first print the digest was computed on a different input (part of it was passed to update and the other part to digest), while the other prints compute the digest of a different input.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanations, I got it sorted out!